# Getting error in the on create method for sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am creating a trivia game for a class assignment. I initially wanted to store the questions with categories in a sqlite database.  I'm strating with one table, though I want to add others for category, level, and users, but first wanted to get it working with just questions.  The program compiles and installs into the emulator and the first part works fine.  It's not until the app goes to create the database that I get an error.  The error reads:

Caused by:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEquestion": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEquestion(questionIDINTEGER PRIMARY KEY,questionNameTEXT,optionATEXT,optionBTEXT,optionCTEXT,answerTEXT,questionLevelIDINTEGER,categoryIDINTEGER)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite
```

My code for the main activity, trivia question activity, question class, DBHelper class and the xml layout for the Trivia Question activity.  Please note, the error occurs when the radio button is selected for a category, which launches the Trivia Question activity. (before adding the database, the launch worked without error). Also, I know I need to create methods for Updating and Deleting records, but wanted to get the database creation working first. I've looked at this for 2 days and cannot find the issue.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

CLASS QUESTION:

```
public class Question {
    private Integer questionID;
    private String questionName;
    private String optionA;
    private String optionB;
    private String optionC;
    private String answer;
    private Integer questionLevelID;
    private Integer categoryID;
    public Question(){
        //// TODO: 11/5/2016
    }
    public Question (Integer questionID, String questionName, String optionA,
                     String optionB, String optionC, String answer, Integer questionLevelID,
                     Integer catID){
        this.questionID=questionID;
        this.questionName=questionName;
        this.optionA=optionA;
        this.optionB=optionB;
        this.optionC=optionC;
        this.answer=answer;
        this.questionLevelID=questionLevelID;
        this.categoryID = catID;

    }
    public void setqID(Integer questionId){
        this.questionID = questionId;
    }
    public void setqName(String questionName){
        this.questionName=questionName;
    }
    public void setqOptA(String optionA){
        this.optionA = optionA;
    }
    public void setqOptB(String optionB){
        this.optionB = optionB;
    }
    public void setqOptC(String optionC){
        this.optionC=optionC;
    }
    public void setqAns(String answer){
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    public void setQLevel(Integer questionLevelID){
        this.questionLevelID = questionLevelID;
    }
    public void setqcatID(Integer categoryID){
        this.categoryID= categoryID;
    }
    public int getqID(){
        return questionID;
    }
    public String getqName(){
        return questionName;
    }
    public String getqOptA(){
        return optionA;
    }
    public String getqOptB(){
        return optionB;
    }
    public String getqOptC(){
        return optionC;
    }
    public String getqAns(){
        return answer;
    }
    public Integer getqLevel(){
        return questionLevelID;
    }
    public Integer getqCatID(){
        return categoryID;
    }
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;


import static android.R.attr.id;

public class EduTriviaMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edu_trivia_main);


    }

    public String onCheckedChanged(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        String category = "";
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.englishRadioButton:
                if (checked) {
                    category = "english";
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,TriviaQuestion.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return category;
                }
                break;

            case R.id.historyRadioButton:
                if (checked) {
                category = "history";
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,TriviaQuestion.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return category;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mathRadioButton:
                if (checked) {
                    category = "math";
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,TriviaQuestion.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return category;
                }
                break;
            default:

                break;

        }
        return category;
    }
}
```

DBHelper Class:

```
   import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    //Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    //Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="eduTrivia";
    //table names

     private static final String TABLE_QUESTION="question";
    //question table column names
    private static final String KEY_QUESTIONID = "questionID";
    private static final String KEY_QUESTION="questionName";
    private static final String KEY_OPTIONA="optionA";
    private static final String KEY_OPTIONB="optionB";
    private static final String KEY_OPTIONC="optionC";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER="answer";
    private static final String KEY_LEVEL = "questionLevelID";
    private static final String KEY_CATEGORYID="categoryID";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION ="CREATE TABLE"
          + TABLE_QUESTION +"("
          + KEY_QUESTIONID +"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
          + KEY_QUESTION + "TEXT,"
          + KEY_OPTIONA + "TEXT,"
          + KEY_OPTIONB + "TEXT,"
          + KEY_OPTIONC + "TEXT,"
          + KEY_ANSWER + "TEXT,"
          + KEY_LEVEL + "INTEGER,"
          + KEY_CATEGORYID + "INTEGER"+")";

          @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION);
        addQuestions();
        }

        private void addQuestions(){
        Question q1 = new Question(1,"How do you write this number using words? 752",
                "five hudnred sixty-two","seven hundred sixty-two", "seven hundred fifty-two",
                "C",1,1);
        Question q2 = new Question(2,"Round 5,764,438 to the nearest hundred thousand",
                "6,200,000","5,800,000","5,700,000","B",1,1);
        Question q3= new Question(3,"Which equation shows the associative property of addition",
                "5+4=3+6","7+(4+3)=(7+4)+3", "0+8=8","B",1,1);
        Question q4 = new Question(4,"Select the adjective in this sentence: Nina is a strong worker",
                "Nina","strong","worker","B",1,2);
        Question q5 = new Question (5,"Select the adjective in this sentence: The twon has three banks",
                "The","town","three","C",1,2);
            }

            @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists"+TABLE_QUESTION);
     onCreate(db);
     }
      //constructor and getInstance() method
    private static DBHandler mDBHANDLER;
        public static synchronized DBHandler getInstance(Context context) {
            if (mDBHANDLER==null){
                mDBHANDLER=new DBHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
            }
            return mDBHANDLER;
        }
    public DBHandler(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
      public void addQuestion(Question question){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUESTIONID,question.getqID());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION,question.getqName());
        values.put(KEY_OPTIONA,question.getqOptA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTIONB,question.getqOptB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTIONC,question.getqOptC());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER,question.getqAns());
        values.put(KEY_LEVEL,question.getqLevel());
        values.put(KEY_CATEGORYID,question.getqCatID());
        db.insert(TABLE_QUESTION,null,values);
        db.close();
    }
            //reading records

            public Question getQuestion(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_QUESTION, new String[]{
            KEY_QUESTIONID, KEY_QUESTION
        },KEY_QUESTIONID + "=?",
        new String[]{
                String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null);
        if (cursor !=null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        Question question = new Question(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)));

        return question;
    }
     public List<Question> getAllQuestions(){
        //Select all questions query
        List questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        String selectAll = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_QUESTION;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectAll,null);
        //loop through all rows and add to the list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Question question = new Question ();
                question.setqID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                question.setqName(cursor.getString(1));
                question.setqOptA(cursor.getString(2));
                question.setqOptB(cursor.getString(3));
                question.setqOptC(cursor.getString(4));
                question.setqAns(cursor.getString(5));
                //adding to list
                questionList.add(question);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return questionList;
    }
    }
```

TRIVIA QUESTION ACTIVITY:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import static android.R.id.list;

public class TriviaQuestion extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Question> questionList;
    int score=0;
    int questionID = 0;
    Question currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestion;
    RadioButton rda,rdb,rdc;
    Button next;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trivia_question);

        DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
        questionList = db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ = questionList.get(questionID);
        txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        setQuestionView();

      }
      private void setQuestionView() {
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getqName());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getqOptA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getqOptB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getqOptC());

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            if (currentQ.getqAns().equals(answer.getText())) {
                score++;
            }
            currentQ = questionList.get(questionID);
            setQuestionView();
        }
     });
    }

}
```

TRIVIA QUESTION LAYOUT XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_trivia_question"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.rasmussenandroid.sandra.edutrivia.TriviaQuestion">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.04" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="next" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you what the issue is - the SQL query is not constructed properly. There should be spaces between the individual terms - for example, CREATE TABLEquestion should be CREATE TABLE question.

Try the following line for CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION :

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION ="CREATE TABLE "
      + TABLE_QUESTION +" ( "
      + KEY_QUESTIONID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
      + KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT , "
      + KEY_OPTIONA + " TEXT, "
      + KEY_OPTIONB + " TEXT, "
      + KEY_OPTIONC + " TEXT, "
      + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, "
      + KEY_LEVEL + " INTEGER, "
      + KEY_CATEGORYID + " INTEGER "+")";
```

Comment: Thank you.  Knew it was something simple.  That fixed the CREATE TABLE error, but now of another error. FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.rasmussenandroid.sandra.edutrivia, PID: 17021java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity TriviaQuestion}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.  Will try and uninstall then reinstall before moving forward.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Accept the answer if you think it is right ! Also, you many want to add some initial questions to the database and also check if it is empty before looking for a specific question.

Comment: I am additing initial questions in the addQuestions function in the DBHelper, which gets called withing the database onCreate.  I put in a check to see if it got created, but still etting the out of bounds exception.